# What is returned by wave.readframes?

Tags: python, wave

I assign a value to a variable `x` in the following way:

```
import wave
w = wave.open('/usr/share/sounds/ekiga/voicemail.wav', 'r')
x = w.readframes(1)
```

When I type x I get:

```
'\x1e\x00'
```

So `x` got a value. But what is that? Is it hexadecimal? `type(x)` and `type(x[0])` tell me that `x` and `x[0]` a strings. Can anybody tell me how should I interpret this strings? Can I transform them into integer?

Answer (score 7):

The interactive interpreter echoes unprintable characters like that. The string contains two bytes, 0x1E and 0x00. You can convert it to an integer with `struct.unpack("<h", x)` (little endian, 2 bytes, signed).

Comment: How would you convert an array of integers back to string in the same format after this?

Comment: @quano: Arrays have the [`.tostring()`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array.tostring) method. For simple sequences, you can use `struct.pack("<4H", 1, 2, 3, 4)`. numpy should also have similar methods.

Comment: Should be "<h" because the audio data in wavs is signed when stored with 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is in hexadecimal, but what it means depends on the other outputs of the wav file e.g. the sample width and number of channels. Your data could be read in two ways, 2 channels and 1 byte sample width (stereo sound) or 1 channel and 2 byte sample width (mono sound). Use `x.getparams()`: the first number will be the number of channels and the second will be the sample width.

[This Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221054954/http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/wave.htm) explains it really well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a two byte string:

```
>>> x='\x1e\x00'
>>> map(ord, list(x))
[30, 0]
>>> [ord(i) for i in x]
[30, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This strings represent bytes. I guess you can turn them into an integer with [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) package, which allows interpreting strings of bytes.