# How to split a byte string into separate parts

Tags: python, arrays, split, byte

I've been trying to create a waveform image and I'm getting the raw data from the `.wav` file using `song = wave.open()` and `song.readframes(1)`, which returns:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

How can I split this into three separate parts, e.g. `b'\x00\x00'`,  `b'\x00\x00'`, `b'\x00\x00'` because each frame consists of 3 parts (each is 2 bytes wide) so I need the value of each individual part to be able to make a wave form.

Comment: [What is returned by wave.readframes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063565/what-is-returned-by-wave-readframes)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use slicing on `byte` objects:

```
>>> value = b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03'
>>> value[:2]
b'\x00\x01'
>>> value[2:4]
b'\x00\x02'
>>> value[-2:]
b'\x00\x03'
```

When handling these frames, however, you probably also want to know about [`memoryview()` objects](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview); these let you interpret the bytes as C datatypes without any extra work on your part, simply by casting a 'view' on the underlying bytes:

```
>>> mv = memoryview(value).cast('H')
>>> mv[0], mv[1], mv[2]
256, 512, 768
```

The `mv` object is now a memory view interpreting every 2 bytes as an unsigned short; so it now has length 3 and each index is an integer value, based on the underlying bytes.

Answer (score 36):

Here is a way that you can split the bytes into a list:

```
data = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
info = [data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
print info
```

gives the result:

```
['\x00\x00', '\x00\x00', '\x00\x00']
```

Answer (score 6):

You are actually asking about serialization/deserialization.  Use struct.pack and struct.unpack (https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).  This gives you nice primitives to do both unpacking and things like endian swapping.  For example:

```
import struct
struct.unpack("<H",b"\x00\x01") # unpacks 2 byte little endian unsigned int
struct.unpack(">l",b"\x00\x01\x02\x03") # unpacks 4 byte big endian signed int
```

Note that your example splits 2 byte words, not bytes.

Since this question is also coming up in searches about splitting binary strings:

```
value = b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03'
split = [value[i] for i in range (0, len(value))]
# now you can modify, for example:
split[1] = 5
# put it back together
joined = bytes(split)
```

Comment: This lookst like the cleanest solution, as it does the work with as less copying and counting as possible. Using `struct.iter_unpack` you can even loop over large blocks of repeating structures.