# Reading a binary file with memoryview

Tags: python, python-2.7, binaryfiles, memoryview

I read a large file in the code below which has a special structure - among others two blocks that need be processed at the same time. Instead of seeking back and forth in the file I load these two blocks wrapped in `memoryview` calls

```
with open(abs_path, 'rb') as bsa_file:
    # ...
    # load the file record block to parse later
    file_records_block = memoryview(bsa_file.read(file_records_block_size))
    # load the file names block
    file_names_block = memoryview(bsa_file.read(total_file_name_length))
    # close the file
file_records_index = names_record_index = 0
for folder_record in folder_records:
    name_size = struct.unpack_from('B', file_records_block, file_records_index)[0]
    # discard null terminator below
    folder_path = struct.unpack_from('%ds' % (name_size - 1),
        file_records_block, file_records_index + 1)[0]
    file_records_index += name_size + 1
    for __ in xrange(folder_record.files_count):
        file_name_len = 0
        for b in file_names_block[names_record_index:]:
            if b != '\x00': file_name_len += 1
            else: break
        file_name = unicode(struct.unpack_from('%ds' % file_name_len,
            file_names_block,names_record_index)[0])
        names_record_index += file_name_len + 1
```

The file is correctly parsed, but as it's my first use of the mamoryview interface I am not sure I do it right. The file_names_block is composed as seen by null terminated c strings.

1. Is my trick `file_names_block[names_record_index:]` using the memoryview magic or do I create some n^2 slices ? Would I need to use `islice` here ?
2. As seen I just look for the null byte manually and then proceed to `unpack_from`. But I read in [How to split a byte string into separate bytes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024532/281545) that I can use `cast()` (docs ?) on the memory view - any way to use that (or another trick) to split the view in bytes ? Could I just call `split('\x00')` ? Would this preserve the memory efficiency ?

I would appreciate insight on the one right way to do this (in python 2).

Comment: I don't think memoryviews are getting you anything here; a memory view, like the `struct` module, has no specific facilities for null-terminated strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `memoryview` is not going to give you any advantages when it comes to null-terminated strings as they have no facilities for anything but fixed-width data. You may as well use `bytes.split()` here instead:

```
file_names_block = bsa_file.read(total_file_name_length)
file_names = file_names_block.split(b'\00')
```

Slicing a `memoryview` doesn't use extra memory (other than the view parameters), but if using a cast you do produce new native objects for the parsed memory region the moment you try to access elements in the sequence.

You can still use the `memoryview` for the `file_records_block` parsing; those strings are prefixed by a length giving you the opportunity to use slicing. Just keep slicing bytes of the memory view as you process `folder_path` values, there's no need to keep an index:

```
for folder_record in folder_records:
    name_size = file_records_block[0]  # first byte is the length, indexing gives the integer
    folder_path = file_records_block[1:name_size].tobytes()
    file_records_block = file_records_block[name_size + 1:]  # skip the null
```

Because the `memoryview` was sourced from a `bytes` object, indexing will give you the integer value for a byte, `.tobytes()` on a given slice gives you a new `bytes` string for that section, and you can then continue to slice to leave the remainder for the next loop.

Comment: Thanks indeed :) I guess I could use split then add `del file_names_block`. As for the one I think it should be shouldn't it be `file_records_block[name_size:]` ? I wonder how fast the memory (of the underlying buffer) is freed after this last operation but this is for the c guys :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: you can use `file_records_block.release()` after the loop to free the `bytes` object.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: I'm not sure what you are asking about regarding `file_records_block[name_size:]` though..

Comment: ooooops - file_records_block[name_size+1:] sorry afternoon nap ! In all do you think my approach buys me anything ? Is it a good way of reading a structured binary file ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: nope, it is `name_size` due to zero-based indexing. So when `name_size` is, say, 4, at index `0` there'll be the `\x04` byte, then indices 1, 2 and 3 are the character bytes. And at index 4 the next string starts.

Comment: Yes in this particular file the name_size includes the null terminating byte - so in your example in position 4 there is this null byte - but case closed :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: ah, misunderstood the structure there then. I thought they were Pascal strings (single-byte length prefix, then length-1 bytes for the string value). Then you do have to slice the next block at `name_size + 1`.