# python weird symbols with wave.readframes() after opening wav file with wave module

Tags: python, audio, wav, wave

I am trying to manipulate wav audio data by using python wave module:

```
import wave

Input=wave.open('engine.wav','rb')
print Input.getparams()
print Input.readframes(1)
```

This is my output:

```
(1, 1, 22050, 1, 'NONE', 'not compressed')
F
```

What does this mysterious symbol 'F' mean here?

I tried to apply the same procedure for different wav files, however, I get the same problem. I suspect it has something to do with encoding, since sometimes I even get Russian symbols as as output of wave.readframes

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063565/what-is-returned-by-wave-readframes).